# GL version 2.1 with the gpu_shared4 extensions is not supported on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS as guest VM

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualbox, vtk

I am trying to run a python (3.6.9) [script](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/blob/16f2bfeac7fa24fbefa1b7b56dbe8b3f23f6fc79/Examples/Rendering/Python/Cylinder.py) with VTK 7.1.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS as guest VM using virtual box. But I am receiving the following error:

```
In /build/vtk7‑w4DzBd/vtk7.1.1+dfsg1/Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 640
vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x2a56080): GL version 2.1 with the gpu_shader4 extension is not supported 
by your graphics driver but is required for the new OpenGL rendering backend. Please update your 
OpenGL driver. If you are using Mesa please make sure you have version 10.6.5 or later and make sure 
your driver in Mesa supports OpenGL 3.2.
```

When I run the command

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

it returns:

```
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 20.0.0-devel - padoka PPA
```

If I understand corretly the visualization on Ubuntu is done by Mesa 20.0.0-devel (required is 10.6.5 - this is OK) but the installed Mesa uses OpenGL 2.1 and not newer (required 3.2 - this is not OK). I have already installed the latest version of Mesa. Any suggestion how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a question in the wrong place, You should try serverfault or askubuntu next time.

Speaking of askbuntu here is a quick answer from there:

> The OpenGL drivers in the VirtualBox Guest Additions are limited to
> OpenGL 2.1. Despite many requests for improved OpenGL capability in
> the VBox user forums I've seen no mention of the VBox developers
> working on OpenGL 3 or better support. That said it only had OpenGL
> 2.0 support around 2009 and has been quietly upgrading to OpenGL 2.1 in the meantime. They may get there.
>
> You always have the option to install software rendering OpenGL
> drivers but they wouldn't be usable for anything beyond the most basic
> requirements. e.g.: there is a software rendering OpenGL32 driver for
> Blender on their FTP site which allows Blender for Windows to actually
> work inside a Windows guest, but frame rates when animating Poses are
> in the 0.5-2.0 fps region. Not nice.
>
> Note that VMware's paid products (VMware Fusion for Mac, VMware
> Workstation for Linux and VMware Workstation for Windows) all have 3D
> capabilities at DirectX 10 and OpenGL 3.3 feature levels. If you're
> willing to pay for them they may work for you (there are trial
> versions available to download and install for free).
>
> You'd think it wouldn't be too hard to port across, all four being
> products of VMware... and it's just a driver for their own virtual
> graphics adapter... right?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/858407/how-to-update-to-latest-opengl-version-on-virtualbox-ubuntu-linux-machine

General idea is that it's the graphics card emulated on the guest that's unable to handle OpenGL version > 2.1

If you're looking into virtualization you might hit up a little project called qemu. I can tell You from personal experience that with the right setup it will do the trick.